# Проблема с выпадающим списком

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Делаю сайт на базе фреймворка Materialize (возможно, это имеет значение), столкнулся с проблемой при верстке мобильной версии меню - пункты имеют подпункты, т.е. нужен выезжающий список. Я его сделал, и все вроде бы хорошо, но при нажатии на такой пункт меню он раскрывается таким образом, что последующие пункты не сдвигаются вниз.
Что интересно, аналогичный список с такой же структурой и скриптом вне мобильного меню работает правильно.

На скринах наглядно проиллюстрировано то, о чем я говорю.

---

Пункты меню, разумеется, не имеют абсолютного позиционирования.. Из-за чего возможно такое поведение? Прошу помочь, мой энтузиазм иссяк.. [Ссылка на верстку](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8yxiu1np0okqk5/Cyprus.rar?dl=0).

UPD: Если кто не хочет качать архив, немного "поехавшая" верстка на [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/BLyyGW) (Сузить экран до появления гамбургера).

UPDD: На код ниже не смотрите - здесь поехало абсолютно все, времени на правку у меня нет, а вставил только потому что иначе не дает добавить ссылку на Кодпен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(".main-menu-mob").sideNav();

$(".fade-scroll-menu .multi-item").click(function () {
  $(this).parent('.fade-scroll-menu > li').find('.submenu').slideToggle("200");
  $(this).find('.arrow-down').toggleClass('rotate-icon');
});
```

```css
/* ======= css reset ======= */
div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre,
form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

fieldset, img, iframe {
    border: 0;
}

ul, nav {
    list-style: none;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

button:focus, a:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
/* ======= css reset ======= */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1920px;
        padding: 0 60px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 16px;
    }
}

/*.container {*/
    /*max-width: 1830px;*/
    /*padding: 0 15px;*/
/*}*/
/*.container .row {*/
    /*margin: 0 -15px;*/
/*}*/
/*.container .col {*/
    /*padding: 0 15px;*/
/*}*/

body {
    font: 16px/36px 'GothamProRegular', verdana, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    color: #8aa5bd;
    text-decoration: none;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: 'GothamProBold',verdana,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #8aa5bd;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 32px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 28px;
}

select, input, textarea {
    background: #edeff3;
    border: 1px solid #edeff3;
}
select:focus, input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #516087;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'GothamProBold',verdana,sans-serif;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.container:after, .container:before, .clearfix:after, .clearfix:before {
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.container:after, .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 120px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* =============================================== */
/* ------------------- HEADER -------------------- */
/* =============================================== */

.header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 500;
}
/* ================== Header-top ================= */
.header-top {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #34363c;
}
.main-menu-mob {
    display: none;
}
/* ------ logo-stick ------ */
.logo-stick {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 3px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 34px;
}
.logo-stick img {
    width: 100%;
}
/* ------ logo-stick ------ */

/* ---- fade-scroll-menu --- */
.fade-menu {
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
}
.fade-scroll-menu {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.fade-scroll-menu.left-side {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: calc(50% - 240px);
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
.fade-scroll-menu.right-side {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: calc(50% - 310px);
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.fade-scroll-menu li {
    text-align: center;
}
.fade-scroll-menu.left-side li {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.fade-scroll-menu.left-side li:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.fade-scroll-menu.left-side li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
    display: none;
}

.fade-scroll-menu.right-side li {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.fade-scroll-menu.right-side li:last-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.fade-scroll-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.fade-scroll-menu li a:hover {
    color: #8aa5bd;
}
.drag-target {
    width: 0;
}
.fade-menu-header {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1660px) {
    .fade-scroll-menu.left-side {
        width: calc(50% - 190px);
        margin-right: 150px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.right-side {
        width: calc(50% - 260px);
        margin-left: 150px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1560px) {
    .fade-scroll-menu {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1490px) {
    .fade-scroll-menu.left-side li {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.right-side li {
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1380px) {
    .fade-scroll-menu {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.left-side {
        width: calc(50% - 180px);
        margin-right: 140px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.right-side {
        width: calc(50% - 250px);
        margin-left: 140px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.left-side li {
        margin-left: 12px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.right-side li {
        margin-right: 12px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1240px) {
    .fade-scroll-menu.left-side {
        width: calc(50% - 170px);
        margin-right: 130px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.right-side {
        width: calc(50% - 240px);
        margin-left: 130px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.left-side li {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .fade-scroll-menu.right-side li {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .logo-stick {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-menu-mob {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -10px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #9a9b9e;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
        -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
        transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    }
    .main-menu-mob:hover {
        color: #9a9b9e;
    }
    .main-menu-mob:active {
        background: rgba(93,94,99,.2);
        color: #9a9b9e;
    }
    .fade-menu {
        position: fixed;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 320px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    /* --- Mob Menu --- */
    #nav-mobile .fade-menu-header {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 48px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 0 16px;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        background: #34363c;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-menu-header .logo-stick-mob {
        width: 134px;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-menu-header img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-menu-header .fade-menu-btn-close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        color: #9a9b9e;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 16px;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu.right-side {
        display: none;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu li {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        line-height: 70px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d7d8;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu li a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #000;
    }

    #nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu .multi-item {
        position: relative;
    }
    #nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu .multi-item .arrow-down {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 30px;
        -webkit-transition: all .25s;
        -moz-transition: all .25s;
        -ms-transition: all .25s;
        -o-transition: all .25s;
        transition: all .25s;
    }
    #nav-mobile .arrow-down.rotate-icon {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    #nav-mobile .submenu {
        display: none;
        padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
    #nav-mobile .submenu li {
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    #nav-mobile .submenu li a {
        font-size: 18px;

    }
    /*#nav-mobile .collapsible-header .arrow-down {*/
        /*position: absolute;*/
        /*right: 0;*/
        /*top: 30px;*/
    /*}*/
    /*#nav-mobile .collapsible-body li {*/
        /*height: 50px;*/
        /*line-height: 50px;*/
    /*}*/
    /*#nav-mobile .collapsible-body li:last-of-type {*/
        /*border-bottom: none;*/
    /*}*/
    /*#nav-mobile .collapsible-body li a {*/
        /*padding-left: 10px;*/
        /*font-size: 18px;*/
    /*}*/
    /* --- Mob Menu --- */
    #sidenav-overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 120vh;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        z-index: 100;
        will-change: opacity;
    }
}
/* ---- fade-scroll-menu --- */

/* ------ central btn ------ */
.send-butt {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 240px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-family: 'GothamProBold',verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.send-butt:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #34363c;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-transform: skew(-15deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg);
    transform: skew(-15deg);
}
.send-butt span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #9a9b9e;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.send-butt:hover,
.send-butt:focus {
    color: #8aa5bd;
}
.send-butt:hover span {
    color: #8aa5bd;
}
/* ------ central btn ------ */

/* ------ right menu ------ */
.pos-rel {
    position: relative;
}
.right-head {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.right-head ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.right-head ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    min-height: 1px;
}
.right-head ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.right-head ul li.drop {
    position: relative;
}
.right-head ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #9a9b9e;
    font-size: 20px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.right-head ul li a:hover {
    color: #8aa5bd;
}

.right-head .dropdown-button:hover, .right-head .dropdown-button.active {
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content {
    top: 100% !important;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 15px;
    right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.dropdown-content ul {
    float: left;
}
.dropdown-content ul li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.dropdown-content ul li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.dropdown-content ul li:hover {
    background: none;
}
.dropdown-content ul li a {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.dropdown-content ul li a:hover, .dropdown-content ul li a:focus {
    color: #8aa5bd;
}
.dropdown-content ul li a span {
    color: #999a9d;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.dropdown-content ul li a:hover span, .dropdown-content ul li a:focus span {
    color: #8aa5bd;
}
.dropdown-content:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 12px 12px 0;
    border-color: transparent #34363c transparent transparent;
}

#phone-drop {
    width: 292px !important;
}
#phone-drop ul {
    padding: 5px 0 10px;
}
#phone-drop .iframe-call {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#social-drop {
    width: 180px !important;
}

/* ------ right menu ------ */
/* ================== Header-top ================= */

/* =============================================== */
/* ------------------- HEADER -------------------- */
/* =============================================== */
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/materialize.min_.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/jquery-1.11.1.min_.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/materialize.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/materialize.min_.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="header-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="header-section pos-rel">
                            <div class="logo-stick">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="img/logo-min.svg" alt="Cyprus">
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="main-menu-mob">
                                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                            </a>

                            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="fade-menu fixed">
                                <div class="fade-menu-header">
                                    <div class="logo-stick-mob">
                                        <a href="#close">
                                            <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/mob-menu-logo.png" />
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#close" class="fade-menu-btn-close icon-close"></a>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="fade-scroll-menu left-side">
                                    <li><a href="#close">Sale</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#close">Rent</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#close">Property managment</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#close">List your property</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#close">Invense / Residence</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#close">Contacts</a></li>
                                    <li class="parent">
                                        <a href="#close" class="multi-item">
                                            Legal advice
                                            <span class="arrow-down">
                                                <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/arrow-down.png" />
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a href="#close">First item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#close">Second item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="parent">
                                        <a href="#close" class="multi-item">
                                            About us
                                            <span class="arrow-down">
                                                <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/arrow-down.png" />
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a href="#close">Third item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#close">Fourth item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                                <ul class="fade-scroll-menu right-side">
                                    <li><a href="#close">Invense / Residence</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#close">Contacts</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>

                            <script>
                                $(".main-menu-mob").sideNav();
                            </script>
                            <script>
                                $(".fade-scroll-menu .multi-item").click(function () {
                                    $(this).parent('.fade-scroll-menu > li').find('.submenu').slideToggle("200");
                                    $(this).find('.arrow-down').toggleClass('rotate-icon');
                                });
                            </script>

                            <div class="right-head">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="viber://tel:132132"><span class="icon-viber"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="skypeto:skype"><span class="icon-skype"></span></a></li>
                                    <li class="drop">
                                        <a class="dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="phone-drop">
                                            <span class="icon-phone"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <div id="phone-drop" class="dropdown-content">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="tel:+35724621001">+357 99811501 <span>(office)</span></a></li>
                                                <li><a href="tel:+35799811501">+357 99811501 <span>(mobile)</span></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <a href="#" class="iframe-call">
                                                <img src="ihttp://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/call.png" alt="">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="drop">
                                        <a class="dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="social-drop"><span class="icon-soc"></span></a><div id="social-drop" class="dropdown-content" style="width: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -155px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-google"></span>Google+ </a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-fb"></span>Facebook </a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-vk"></span>Vkontakte </a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- right-head -->


                            <a class="send-butt modal-trigger" href="#send-a-request">
                                <span class="icon-send"></span>SEND A REQUEST
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        </div><!-- header-section pos-rel -->
                    </div><!-- container -->
                </div><!-- header-top -->
                <div class="header-bottom">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div style="height: 20px; background: #cecece;">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- header -->
        </div><!-- wrapper -->


        <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не могли бы выложить верстку, например, сюда: http://jsfiddle.net? Минимальный пример, отражающий вашу проблему

Comment: Виталий, продублировал проблему в кодпене, ссылка выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому-что основной пункт меню `#nav-mobile .fade-scroll-menu li` имеет фиксированную высоту `height: 70px`. Подпункты появляясь не могут его расширить. Смотрите внимательно.

379 строка main.css